# How to allocate arrays inside a kernel using numba?

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I am trying to allocate some arrays inside a `for` loop that is inside a Kernel. The Kernel looks like this:

```
@cuda.jit
def forcecudatiling(p_num,d_num,r,force):
    threadsInBlock=cuda.blockDim.x
    threadsInGrid=threadsInBlock*cuda.gridDim.x
    tid=cuda.threadIdx.x + cuda.blockIdx.x*cuda.blockDim.x
    tiles=p_num/cuda.blockDim.x + 1
    shared_p_mx = cuda.shared.array(0,dtype=np.float32)
    shared_p_my = cuda.shared.array(0,dtype=np.float32)
    alpha=(1.5)
    rho=(1.0)
    beta=(1.5*(1.0+alpha))
    for k in range(tid,p_num,threadsInGrid):
        r_k=cuda.device_array((d_num,p_num))
        forcetemp=cuda.device_array((d_num,p_num))
        r_k[0,k]=r[0,k]
        r_k[1,k]=r[1,k]
        forcetemp[0,k]=0.0
        forcetemp[1,k]=0.0
```

The arrays that I am trying to allocate are `r_k`, and `forcetemp` but with the above code I get the following error:

> TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython
>   frontend) Unknown attribute 'device_array' of type Module()
>
> File "", line 117: def
>   forcecudatiling(p_num,d_num,r,force):
>       
>       for k in range(tid,p_num,threadsInGrid):
>           r_k=cuda.device_array((d_num,p_num))

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to allocate some arrays inside a for loop that is inside a
>   Kernel

You can't do that. No memory allocation or array creation is  [supported](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/cuda/cudapysupported.html#numpy-support) in Numba CUDA kernels.